# Vim -- Enumerate Lines in Base26

Tags: vim, line-numbers

Is there any standard way to specify the set of characters that vim uses to enumerate lines? For example, instead of numbers in succession, could I use lower-case letters {a, b, ..., aa, ab, ac, ...} (or even better, use only the characters in a keyboard's home row) and still act on specific lines by this new referencing system?

I suppose an escape key of sorts -- perhaps ':' or 'g' -- might be needed, but even so, if anyone has suggestions as to how I could implement this, I'd be quite appreciative.

Thanks.

Comment: what does a non-number "linenumber" bring you? E.g. `a,b...aa,bb..` what is your ultimate goal?

Comment: Line "numbering" with a home row letters may be useful if you often need to switch to an arbitrary line, probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built-in other than absolute and relative line numbers, and it would be difficult to square a different addressing scheme with the numerical `[count]` prefixes to the Vim motions. However, plugins like [EasyMotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3526) and [vim-seek](https://github.com/goldfeld/vim-seek) implement such, though for motions like the built-in `f` *inside* a line.

For implementation tips, have a look at the [RltvNmbr.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2351); it uses the *sign column* to emulate the now built-in relative numbering. As the sign column is two characters wide (and can display arbitrary characters), this would be fitting. That would take care of the visualization... you'd then only need a custom mapping to query for the Base26 line number, and translate that back into a jump.